# Importing product into prestashop using prestapyt

Tags: python, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i am trying to import new products in my shop through a python script. I don't have any error when executing it, but i can't see any product on my shop afterward.
Here's my script:

```
import requests
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebServiceDict
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import sys


args = sys.argv
if len(args) < 2:
    print('Please give a ref and a number')
    exit()

reference = args[1]

shop = 'AIO'
presta_url = 'URL'
base_url = 'URL'

prestashop = PrestaShopWebServiceDict(presta_url, 'KEY')
auth = ('KEY', '')

product = prestashop.search('products', options={'filter[reference]': '[' + reference + shop + ']'})

if not product:
    product_schema = prestashop.get('products', options={'schema': 'blank'})
    print(product_schema)
    product_schema['product'].update({'active': '1',
                                     'additional_shipping_cost': '',
                                     'advanced_stock_management': '',
                                     'description': {'language': {'attrs': {'id': '2'}, 'value': 'DESCRIPTION!!!'}},
                                     'description_short': {'language': {'attrs': {'id': '2'},
                                                                        'value': 'SHORT DESCRIPTION!!!'}},
                                     'id_category_default': '2',
                                     'name': {'language': {'attrs': {'id': '2'}, 'value': 'NAME'}},
                                     'new': '1',
                                     'price': 23.0,
                                     'reference': 'MYREF',
                                     'show_price': '1',
                                     'width': ''})
    print(product_schema)
    test = prestashop.add('products', product_schema)
    print(test)
```

I do not not what to try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that i'll post here: (presta_url and base_url are both the url to access the webservice). 
First we add up the product in the store you chose, then after the product creation we upload the images. Hope this will help.

```
product = prestashop.search('products', options={'filter[reference]': '[' + reference + ']'})
    if product:
        base_url = base_url + str(product[0])
        r = requests.delete(base_url, auth=auth, allow_redirects=True)
        print('DELETED: ' + reference)
    if active == '1':
        product_xml = "<prestashop> \
        <product> \
            <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer> \
            <id_supplier>0</id_supplier> \
            <id_category_default xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/categories/" + id_category + "'>" + id_category + "</id_category_default> \
            <new/> \
            <cache_default_attribute>0</cache_default_attribute> \
            <id_default_image xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/images/products/353/699' notFilterable='true'>699</id_default_image> \
            <id_default_combination notFilterable='true'/> \
            <id_tax_rules_group xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/tax_rule_groups/1'>1</id_tax_rules_group> \
            <position_in_category notFilterable='true'>0</position_in_category> \
            <type notFilterable='true'>simple</type> \
            <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default> \
            <reference>" + reference + "</reference> \
            <supplier_reference/> \
            <location/> \
            <width>0.000000</width> \
            <height>0.000000</height> \
            <depth>0.000000</depth> \
            <weight>0.000000</weight> \
            <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount> \
            <ean13/> \
            <isbn/> \
            <upc/> \
            <cache_is_pack>0</cache_is_pack> \
            <cache_has_attachments>0</cache_has_attachments> \
            <is_virtual>0</is_virtual> \
            <state>1</state> \
            <additional_delivery_times>1</additional_delivery_times> \
            <delivery_in_stock> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </delivery_in_stock> \
            <delivery_out_stock> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </delivery_out_stock> \
            <on_sale>0</on_sale> \
            <online_only>0</online_only> \
            <ecotax>0.000000</ecotax> \
            <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity> \
            <low_stock_threshold/> \
            <low_stock_alert>0</low_stock_alert> \
            <price>" + price + "</price> \
            <wholesale_price>0.000000</wholesale_price> \
            <unity/> \
            <unit_price_ratio>0.000000</unit_price_ratio> \
            <additional_shipping_cost>0.00</additional_shipping_cost> \
            <customizable>0</customizable> \
            <text_fields>0</text_fields> \
            <uploadable_files>0</uploadable_files> \
            <active>" + active + "</active> \
            <redirect_type/> \
            <id_type_redirected>0</id_type_redirected> \
            <available_for_order>1</available_for_order> \
            <available_date>0000-00-00</available_date> \
            <show_condition>0</show_condition> \
            <condition>new</condition> \
            <show_price>1</show_price> \
            <indexed>1</indexed> \
            <visibility>both</visibility> \
            <advanced_stock_management>0</advanced_stock_management> \
            <date_add>2018-12-10 12:01:10</date_add> \
            <date_upd>2018-12-10 12:01:10</date_upd> \
            <pack_stock_type>3</pack_stock_type> \
            <meta_description> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </meta_description> \
            <meta_keywords> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </meta_keywords> \
            <meta_title> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </meta_title> \
            <name> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'>" + name + "</language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'>" + name + "</language> \
            </name> \
            <description> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'>" + description + "</language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'>" + description + "</language> \
            </description> \
            <description_short> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'>" + description_short + "</language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'>" + description_short + "</language> \
            </description_short> \
            <available_now> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </available_now> \
            <available_later> \
                <language id='1' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/1'></language> \
                <language id='2' xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/languages/2'></language> \
            </available_later> \
            <associations> \
                <categories nodeType='category' api='categories'> \
                    <category xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/categories/" + id_category + "'> \
                        <id>" + id_category + "</id> \
                    </category> \
                </categories> \
                <combinations nodeType='combination' api='combinations'/> \
                <product_option_values nodeType='product_option_value' api='product_option_values'/> \
                <product_features nodeType='product_feature' api='product_features'> \
                    " + feature_string + " \
                </product_features> \
                <tags nodeType='tag' api='tags'/> \
                <stock_availables nodeType='stock_available' api='stock_availables'> \
                    <stock_available xlink:href='" + presta_url + "/stock_availables/353'> \
                        <id>353</id> \
                        <id_product_attribute>0</id_product_attribute> \
                    </stock_available> \
                </stock_availables> \
                <accessories nodeType='product' api='products'/> \
                <product_bundle nodeType='product' api='products'/> \
            </associations> \
        </product> \
    </prestashop>"
        print('STARTING:' + shop)
        test = prestashop.add('products', product_xml)
        product = prestashop.search('products', options={'filter[reference]': '[' + reference + ']'})
        for image in images:
            file_name = '<path_to_images>/' + image
            fd = io.open(file_name, "rb")
            content = fd.read()
            fd.close()
            prestashop.add('/images/products/' + str(product[0]), files=[('image', file_name, content)])
            print('SENT:' + image)
        print('DONE:' + shop)
```